# Phonegap Google Maps marker icon - When set to optimised:false loose click event

Tags: cordova, maps, google-maps-markers

I´m using PhoneGAP to build a native geolocation app, everything is good so far, i´m using custom icons, when i set the custom icon to optimised:true i loose the retina resolution (google maps creates a sprite with non-retina resolution with my icon) but i can click on the icon and get the infobox to show.

The issue comes when i change optimised to false, when i do that i loose the click event and i cant figure how to enable the event again, here is the code for this:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng($(xml).find('lat').eq(iterator).text(), $(xml).find('lng').eq(iterator).text()),
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: friendMarker,
          optimized: false,
          clickable: true
        });

The markers are placed on the map correctly and everything works fine but the click event on the markers with optimised:false, when set to true they work but i see the markers blurred on retina devices.

Any help with be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already fix it? Having similar problems here... Markers are displayed weird (they are streched and half covered by map panels)... I have to fix this soon...